# solution to $\frac{dy}{dx} = \cos^2(y) 2x$ with initial condition $y(0) = 9$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is fairly simple to solve that $\tan(y) = x^2 + 9$, but my teacher said that it would be incorrect to leave it in this form, but she did not know why. Why would you need to take the arctangent of both sides, and why would it be incorrect to say that this differential equation does not yield the function $y= \tan^{-1}(x^2+9)$, but the relation $\tan(y) = x^2 + 9$?

Comment: Note that $\tan(9)\neq 9.$

Comment: did you mean to write $\tan(y) = x^2 + \tan(9)?$

Answer (score 1):

The problem is to solve the equation for $y$, not for $\tan(y)$. We have
$$\tan(y)=x^2+C$$
for some constant $C$, so
$$y=\arctan(x^2+C)+k\pi$$
for some integer $k$, and since
$$y(0)=\arctan(C)+k\pi=9$$
we have
$$C=\tan(9-k\pi)=\tan(9)\mathrm{.}$$
Thus
$$y=\arctan(x^2+\tan(9))+k\pi$$
for some integer $k$.